# get the taken path until a line in python

Tags: python, if-statement, stack, stack-trace

Given a python function with nested if-else statements, how can we get the path we have taken to arrive to a line.

```
def function():
   if condition1:
      if condition2:
         sth
      else:
         get_path()
   else:
      sth
```

In this case, when the function `function` runs, `get_path()` should return something like `function.condition1.not(condition2)`

I dont' want to build the path myself, I thought about using the module `inspect` and seeing what is being stored in the stack frame, but I think it will require some treatment to get the path. Is there any easier way ?

Comment: Maybe you can use some prints...

Comment: I don't want to create the path myself, this way if the code changes, I don't have to update anything. I would like to use what the interpreter already knows and delegate this task to it.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to trace what happened throughout execution of the function; you can simply use `trace` ([read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html)) as shown below:

```
import sys
import trace

# create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
# do tracing or line-counting or both.
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

def test():
    if True:
        if False:
            print('one')
        else:
            print('two')

# run the new command using the given tracer
tracer.run('test()')

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

Output:

```
>>>>>> import sys
>>>>>> import trace

       # create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
       # do tracing or line-counting or both.
>>>>>> tracer = trace.Trace(
>>>>>>     ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
>>>>>>     trace=0,
>>>>>>     count=1)

>>>>>> def test():
           if True:
               if False:
                   print('here')
               else:
    1:             print('here2')

       # run the new command using the given tracer
>>>>>> tracer.run('test()')

       # make a report, placing output in the current directory
>>>>>> r = tracer.results()
>>>>>> r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

The above will produce a `.cover` file with the tracing results; or you'll have to play around with strings and/or a list of actions and use that as the path taken.

Easiest way of doing it:

```
def function():
    path = 'function'

    if condition1:
        path += '.condition1'

        if condition2:
            path += '.condition2'
        else:
            path += '.not(condition2)'
    else:
        path += '.not(condition1)'
```

This is an example; its not scale-able but will satisfy a tiny need.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I need the path to be retrieved in real-time; while the function runs.

Comment: Then the easiest way is to generate your own path.

Comment: @TorTor added the example of playing around with strings for you.

Answer (score 0):

This simple method ,convenient for small paths only and user-defined, requires no library .You can create a list and append to that list the corresponding tags for if-conditions( which would append only if the condition satisfies).So any time you feel you can print the list in the order the events happened!